# Distribution of random vector divided by its norm?

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-analysis, linear-algebra, ratio

Does anyone know anything about the distribution of a random vector divided by it's norm?  More specifically, if we know the distribution of a vector valued random variable $x$, what can we say about the distributions of $\frac{\vec{x}}{\Vert\vec{x}\Vert_2}$ and $\frac{\vec{x}}{\Vert\vec{x}\Vert^2_2}$

1. In general.
2. If $\vec{x} \sim \mathcal N_p(\vec{\mu}, \Sigma).$

Comment: If $x$ is uniformly distributed, the normalized one is is uniformly distributed on the unit hyperball.

Comment: (1) is too general to obtain much useful information.  (2) has been asked here, but unfortunately it would be difficult to search for that thread. I recall that an answer has been obtained but it is not a straightforward one except when $\Sigma$ is orthogonal and $\mu=0$ (which makes the normalized distribution uniform on the unit sphere).

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for the information.  Any vague recollections on how to go about searching for the old threads?  I'd be keen to learn more about this.

Comment: @MarcClaesen "uniformly distributed" won't be sufficient on its own for that to hold. If it's uniformly distributed **in the unit ball**, then the normalized one would be uniform on the surface, but it wouldn't be true of $x$ uniform on $[0,1]^d$.

Comment: @trendymoniker See my answer here:http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263896/moment-mgf-of-cosine-of-two-random-vectors